# A vector bundle associated to a codimension $1$ submanifold of a symplectic manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes, foliations

We  consider the  standard  symplectic structure  $\omega=\sum dx_i\wedge dy_i$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. To  every codimension $1$ submanifold  $M\subset \mathbb{R}^{2n}$  we  associate a  vector  bundle $E$ over $M$ as follows:

$$E=\{(x,v)\in M\times \mathbb{R}^{2n}\mid \omega(v,N_x)=0,\;\;N_x\perp T_x M\}$$

> Does the  structure of this  bundle $E$, or at least its  characteristic  classes,  depend  on the way $M$ is  embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$? What can be said about orientability of this bundle?   What is the  structure of this  bundle for  the  standard odd dimensional spheres?Is it trivial?is  it isomorphic to the tangent bundle of  sphere?

**Note:** One can extend this question by  replacing  $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ with an arbitrary  symplectic  Riemannian manifold. Moreover the intersection of this  bundle $E$ with $TM$ gives us a codimension $1$ distribution of $M$. So it would be interesting to study the dependency  (and integrability and the structure of the foliation generated by) of this  distribution on the  way of  embedding of  $M$ in the ambient symplectic manifold. As an  example: What is  this  distribution for $S^3$?

Comment: Stupid question: what is $N_x$? Is it the _Euclidean_ normal bundle, or the symplectic one? In the first case, you should change the title of your question. In the second, $E$ is just the tangent bundle.

Comment: @SebastianGoette  Your comment is helpful. May be I should be more precise in the question. Yes it is Euclidean normal bundle, as I wrote $N_x \perp T_x M$.  So what should be the title in this case?

Comment: I am not quite sure if there is anything better than "symplectic manifold with compatible metric". You probably don't want something strong like Kähler, do you?

Comment: @SebastianGoette  Very good suggestion: However I did not pay attention to this situation and I did not include in the title, but the main example I considered in the body of the question is avtually Kahler. But can the extra assumption Kahlerian help us to say somethong?

Comment: The isomorphism in my answer below would be parallel, and hence even the Chern-Weil forms would agree. But then, for the question if $E\cap TM$ becomes a contact structure, the Kähler condition is irrelevant as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to choose a compatible Riemannian metric $g$ to define the normal bundle $N$. Then the almost complex structure $J$ defined by $\omega$ and $g$ induces an isomorphism between $E$ and $TM$.

As for your second question, assume that $M=f^{-1}(0)$ for some function $f$ that has $0$ as a regular value. Then $E\cap TM$ is perpendicular to the Hamiltonian vector field of $f$ acting on $M$.
Let $\alpha\in\Omega^1(M)$ be a (local) defining one-form, so $\ker\alpha=E\cap TM$. If $E\cap TM$ is integrable, we can find $\alpha$ such that $d\alpha=0$. Equivalently, we demand $\alpha\wedge d\alpha=0$, which is independent of the choice of $\alpha$.

On the other hand, if $\alpha\wedge(d\alpha)^{n-1}$ is a volume form (nonzero everywhere), then $E\cap TM$ is called a contact structure. Again, this condition does not depend on the choice of $\alpha$. This includes the case of the standard sphere $S^{2n-1}\subset\mathbb R^{2n}$.

Comment: Thanks for your very interesting answer. $J$ was very key point which I dod mot pay attention to.

Comment: To define a normal line bundle a metric is sufficient, not a compatible metric.

Comment: BTW what can be said precisely about the distribution of the standard $S^3$?If it is integrable of course it can not have a leaf with non trivial holonomy sonce all datas are  analytic.

Comment: So what is the dynamical behaviour of this possible foliation?

Comment: We do not need to "choose " any metric. The metric and symplectic syructure are fixed already.  But I think we choose a compatible  almost complex syructure. Yes?

Comment: My apology if my question is elementary: Can the method of your answer be used to give an affirmative answer to the following question? **Question:** Let M be a compact orientable n dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ where $n$ is odd. Does  $M$ admit a non vanishing vector field $X$ such that $\omega(X,TM)=0$?

Comment: Dear @AliTaghavi, for your first questions I strongly recommend some basic course in contact geometry. I am sure that the contact structure on a sphere is one of the examples treated there. For your last question, consider the n-torus as a product of $n$ copies of $S^1\subset\mathbb R^2$. This is an example of a Lagrangian submanifold, so $\omega|_{T^n}=0$ identically.

Comment: Sorry, the Lagrangian torus is of course only one example. I would have to think about the general question.

Comment: yes that is an interesting example but I search for general case. I asked this as an independent question in the linked post. Thank you for your attention to my question.